# How to manage Nodejitsu created MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nodejitsu

I've created a new MongoDB using the command:

```
jitsu databases create mongodb my_datbase
```

Now I'm not sure how to manage this newly created database. When I try to use the given details in my app, I end up with "An error has occurred: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}".

How do I check the db is running ok?

Comment: Depends on the OS your on but a lot of the time try running `mongo` program and querying for the database

Comment: The [MongoDB tutorial](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Tutorial) has examples of connecting using the command line `mongo` shell and doing some basic queries.  There is also a short [interactive tutorial at try.mongodb.org](http://try.mongodb.org/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should have received a url from [jitsu](https://github.com/nodejitsu/jitsu) that looked something like

```
mongodb://username:password@somehost.mongohq.com:port/database
```

You can pass this information into pretty much any mongodb connection tool, though usually not as a raw connection string (mongoose is an exception). For example, with the `mongo` cli client:

```
mongo somehost.mongohq.com:port/database -u usernamd -p password
```

and there you go!